# Pattern Preview in one axis only

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, tiles

In Photoshop, the pattern preview mode in Photoshop displays both the horizontal and vertical axes, but I only want it to be horizontal only. Is there any way to achieve this? Offset is just too cumbersome for me and doesn't work as intuitively as pattern preview.
Right now, the pattern preview looks like this:

[image: current pattern preview]

I want it to look something like this
[image: what I want it to be]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. As far as I know this isn't possible.  The pattern preview has no options like that. It's designed for creating seamless tileable patterns, so it would kind of defeat the purpose if it didn't show a fully tiled pattern.